# Adding standalone.xml to JBoss WildFly Docker container

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly

I have a Java EE8 Application which is deployed on JBoss WildFly 16.0.0.Final and it accesses MongoDB using Hibernate OGM.

I have built a customised Docker container

```
FROM jboss/wildfly    

# ARG are also known as build-time variables
ARG EAR_FILE=./build/libs/GoStopHandle.ear
ARG WILDFLY_MODULES=./wildfly-as/16.0.0.Final/modules

# Add
COPY ${WILDFLY_MODULES}/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/search/ /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/search/
COPY ${WILDFLY_MODULES}/org/hibernate/hql/ /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/org/hibernate/hql/
COPY ${WILDFLY_MODULES}/org/hibernate/ogm/ /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/
COPY ${WILDFLY_MODULES}/system/layers/base/org/apache/lucene/ /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/lucene/

COPY ./mysqldatabase/mysql/main/ /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysqldatabase/mysql/main/
RUN ls -la /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysqldatabase/mysql/main/

RUN ls -la /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/search/
RUN ls -la /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/org/hibernate/hql/
RUN ls -la /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/org/hibernate/ogm/
RUN ls -la /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/lucene/

#ADD standalone-full.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
#RUN ls -la /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/

#ADD standalone.conf /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/
#RUN ls -la /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/

# Add the GoStopHandle ear to the container
ADD ${EAR_FILE} /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin welcome1 --silent
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

and added the required modules/JARS for Hibernate OGM and ADDed my EAR.

I can build and run the Docker image and it starts okay, albeit not being able to connect to the MongoDB container. I need to add my DataSources etc.

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND
>   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
>   NAMES f0e0c4a948ec        gostophandle        "/opt/jboss/wildfly/…"
>   22 hours ago        Up 22 hours         0.0.0.0:32779->8080/tcp
>   blissful_newton 93e95917216d        mongo
>   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   22 hours ago        Up 22 hours
>   0.0.0.0:27017-27019->27017-27019/tcp   goStopHandleMongo

So I ADD my: standalone.conf & standalone-full.xml

```
ADD standalone-full.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
ADD standalone.conf /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/
```

Even though the Docker image builds it now won’t run just returns:

```
MacBook-Pro:GoStopHandle NOTiFY$ sudo docker run -d -p 8080 gostophandle:latest
Password:
f3a6b533893f0cbfc8ab14604c7a780440ff8b568c2136a2c7db11ffa856939c
MacBook-Pro:GoStopHandle NOTiFY$
```

Comment: Can't really say what is going on without logs from the container. Please provide the output of `docker logs stopped_containerId` in your post. Stopped container id can be retrieved with `docker ps -a`.

Comment: My answer shows the log and the cause -> 'PrintGCDateStamps', which is a Java 8 feature. Have removed this and all is okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to your

> standalone config with

```
 -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-my-full.xml
```